# how can I fix npm install sqlite3 fail?

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, npm

I am using windows sub linux (ubuntu) for my project and tried to install sqlite3 using `npm install sqlite3`

Here is my error:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> sqlite3@5.0.1 install /mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.1 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
make: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 0.00041 s in the future
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a
  COPY Release/nothing.a
  ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3.c
/bin/sh: 1: python: not found
make: *** [deps/action_before_build.target.mk:13: Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3.c] Error 127
make: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rkim964/.npm/_logs/2021-02-05T00_40_18_352Z-debug.log
```

Is there any idea I can fix this?
I have tried to delete package-lock.json and node_module and did npm install again but doesn't work for me.

Addition to this I have run `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

the result was

```
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.2
node-pre-gyp info using node@10.19.0 | linux | x64
node-pre-gyp info build requesting source compile
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
gyp info using node@10.19.0 | linux | x64
gyp info ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: backend package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready:
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack package.json must declare these properties:
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack main
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_name
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.module_path
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack binary.host
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at validate_config (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:220:15)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.module.exports.evaluate (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/versioning.js:279:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at handle_gyp_opts (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/handle_gyp_opts.js:59:27)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at configure (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/configure.js:12:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/build.js:43:13
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:85:9)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /mnt/c/Users/window/Documents/IEEE-Website/backend
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.19.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.2
node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
```

This is what I have got

Comment: It's clearly saying `/bin/sh: 1: python: not found`. What's the output of `which python` from a shell?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux tools/apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum asking questions about setting up development tools IS on topic here

Comment: @BahmanM "which python" does not show me anything but "which python3" shows up

Comment: Oh. Easy then. Just `sudo apt-get install python` to install python2 - which currently on most Debian/Ubuntu distros is referred to as just "python" out of the box.

Comment: i actually found the solution. It is `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3`. As ubuntu devide python as python2 and python3 command so you need map the python to python3 which 'sudo apt-get install python-is-python3` does it for ubuntu user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually found the solution. It is `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3`. As ubuntu devide python as python2 and python3 command so you need map the python to python3 which `sudo apt-get install python-is-python3` does it for ubuntu user